# running mvc3 applicaiton error 'It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I just have created a new MVC3 application. It was running fine but just when i try to add authentication settings in web.config it started throwing the below error:

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level

My Web.config code is as below:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>

<profile>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>

<roleManager enabled="false">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Comment: Check and delete anything in your Obj folder in your project.  There will probably be at least one folder matching the name(s) of your build configurations (eg. Debug and Release).  It is safe to delete these and then re-run your app to see if it works.

Comment: Thanks @Tommy, I have deleted every thing form Obj folder but issues is still same. Can you please advice ?

Comment: Are you debugging locally in VS or is this an error from a server deployment?

Comment: I am developing locally in VS 2010.

Comment: My only other suggestion would be to ensure that you do not have multiple web.configs in your solution.